# Checking if BlobCaching is enabled in Sharepoint (without looking at the web.config)

Tags: sharepoint, caching, sharepoint-2007, blob

Does anyone know if there is a boolean value somewhere in the object model that allows me to check if blobcaching is enabled or not?  I've just been unable to locate it, looking through intellisense for SPContext and a few other places.  Google turned up nothing outside of the web.config.  I was hoping to find something under SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication, but nothing.

I can always create my own static property that programmatically looks into the web.config to find out, but would rather not reinvent the wheel if such a property already exists somewhere I didn't think to look.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are no properties available to check if its enabled or disabled (apart from looking in the web.config). So you will have to read through your web.config. There are however some articles concerning how to reset/clear the blob cache:

[example 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nehajain/archive/2009/05/25/how-to-automatically-reset-clear-the-blob-cache-disk-cache-programmatically.aspx)